# Why does checkmarx mark this as a XSS vulnerability?

Tags: xss, checkmarx

I have the following code in a HTML file -

```
<div class="dropdown" data-type="all">
```

Checkmarx has identified this statement as a potential XSS vulnerability. This is the first line in the HTML file (it's a template / partial that will be inserted into something else).

My question is - why is it marked as a potential XSS vulnerability? I did read the OWASP pages about it and understand that I need to escape the values assigned to the attributes but as you can see, the values for the attributes are just fine.

Answer (score 1):

If that is the first line in the file, then it may be that Checkmarx is not marking the right place in the code. Take a look at the result's source line number and destination line number (shown in the table on the bottom) that should point you to the place where the input is received, and where the value that is affected by the input, is printed.

PS, if you are using IE to view the scan results, try switching to Chrome or Firefox, maybe the result will render better on those browsers.